# LZW compression creating huge files in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using a recent version of [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/) on Windows 10 to resize and compress `.tif` files with `mogrify *.tif -resize 20% -compress lzw`.  The input files are all the same dimensions and weigh a few hundred to a thousand KB, but the output files are all the same size, around 138 MB.  This suggests to me that the mogrified files are being stored uncompressed.  Using `mogrify *.tif -compress zip` leaves the files at their inflated size.

Why is the compression step failing?

Output of `magick -version`:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-35 Q16-HDRI x64 ff6dbbb:20220516 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenCL OpenMP(2.0)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg jxl lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raqm raw rsvg tiff webp xml zip zlib
Compiler: Visual Studio 2022 (193231328)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of commands is important: success was obtained with `mogrify -resize 20% -compress lzw *.tif`.